# How to do empty input after clone in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple inputs and I'm doing clone this inputs this is working fine but I want empty input should be clone. How can I do that?

```js
$('.add-more-room-btn').click(function() {
  let addMoreRoomClone = $(this).parents('.room-info-parents').find('.room-info .row:first').clone();
  $(this).parents('.room-info-parents').find('.room-info').append(addMoreRoomClone);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="room-info-parents">
  <div class="room-info">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h5>Room Info</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group custom-form-group">
          <label>Bed & mattress</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group custom-form-group">
          <label>AC</label>
          <select class="form-control">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group custom-form-group">
          <label>Wooden Floor</label>
          <select class="form-control">
            <option>Select</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group custom-form-group">
          <label>FAN</label>
          <select class="form-control">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group custom-form-group">
          <label>TV</label>
          <select class="form-control">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group custom-form-group">
          <label>TV</label>
          <select class="form-control">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group custom-form-group">
          <label>TV</label>
          <select class="form-control">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group custom-form-group">
          <label>TV</label>
          <select class="form-control">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="mt-3 btn btn-outline-primary add-more-room-btn">Add More</button>
</div>
```

Thankyou!

Comment: `.find('.room-info .row:first').clone()` => `.find('.room-info .row:first').clone().val('')`? Or `addMoreRoomClone.val('')` before appending it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find input and empty it before append:

```
addMoreRoomClone.find('input').val('')
```

```js
$('.add-more-room-btn').click(function() {
        let addMoreRoomClone = $(this).parents('.room-info-parents').find('.room-info .row:first').clone();
        addMoreRoomClone.find('input').val('')
        $(this).parents('.room-info-parents').find('.room-info').append(addMoreRoomClone);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="room-info-parents">
    <div class="room-info">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h5>Room Info</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group custom-form-group">
                    <label>Bed & mattress</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group custom-form-group">
                    <label>AC</label>
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group custom-form-group">
                    <label>Wooden Floor</label>
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>Select</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group custom-form-group">
                    <label>FAN</label>
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group custom-form-group">
                    <label>TV</label>
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group custom-form-group">
                    <label>TV</label>
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group custom-form-group">
                    <label>TV</label>
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group custom-form-group">
                    <label>TV</label>
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="mt-3 btn btn-outline-primary add-more-room-btn">Add More</button>
</div>
```